# What's the different between ASP.NET AJAX pageLoad() and JavaScript window.onload?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm working with ASP.NET AJAX and want to understand the difference between these two snippets:

```
function pageLoad(sender, eventArgs) { }
```

and

```
window.onload = function() { }
```

- Do they act the same?
- Or is one called before the other?
- Or will one be called automatically and the another not?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A couple things to note first. MS invented a sort of "clientside runtime object" called [`Sys.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310856(loband).aspx). It handles raising `init`, `load`, and `unload` events throughout the [clientside] lifespan of the page, as follows:

1. [`Sys.Application.initialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311012(loband).aspx) begins the `init` part of the life cycle. This `initialize()`s all clientside AJAX controls, after which they're ready to be interacted with programatically
2. `Sys.Application` begins the `load` part of the life cycle, calling all handlers that have subscribed to this event
3. Finally, it calls the global function `pageLoad` (if one is defined)

Step 2) and 3) are repeated for every partial (ie AJAX + UpdatePanel) postback.

**So finally the answer**: `pageLoad` is just a handy shortcut to [`Sys.Application.add_load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829(loband).aspx).

With regards to its relationship to `window.onload` however, things start to get interesting. Essentially, MS needed `window.onload` to fire only *after* the `init` phase was complete. But you can't control when the browser will fire `onload`, as it's tied to *"content loaded"*. This is known as ["the `window.onload` problem"](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/09/busted/):

> onload event fires after all page
>   content has loaded (including images
>   and other binary content). If your
>   page includes lots of images then you
>   may see a noticeable lag before the
>   page becomes active.

So, they just invented their own "special" function to fire at just the right time in their event life cycle and called it `"pageLoad"`. And the trick that they used to kickoff this custom event life cycle was to [place the call to `Sys.Application.initialize()` just before the closing `</form>` tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311012(loband).aspx). The serverside runtime does this. Astute readers will note that this trick allowed MS to solve the `window.onload` problem, since any code you put into `pageLoad` will fire independent of binary content ([w/ one rare catch for IE](http://seejoelprogram.wordpress.com/2008/06/08/when-sysapplicationinitialize-causes-operation-aborted-in-ie/)).

**> Do they act the same?**

Conceptually yes, in practice not at all due to said `window.onload` problem. The only rule is that you should put code that interacts with your AJAX controls in `pageLoad` only, since `window.onload` follows its own event trajectory.

**> Or is one called before the other?**

They are completely, 100% independent.

**> Or will one be called automatically and the another not?**

They will both be called if you have them defined.

Comment: your answer is complete, but i have another issue with pageLoad, when i put in my page i found that it keep called and called automatically, note: i have telerik:RadAjaxManager on the page, so this is because of an error happening or its normal to keep called like that "as its called by a timer"?

Comment: nice write up +1 - the </form> solution is so very laughably microsoft

Comment: @amrelgarhy: see my updated answer: Step 2) and 3) are called on every partial (ie AJAX + UpdatePanel) postback.

Comment: @crescentfresh: +1. Why did you delete your other answer? It's more or less the same. *looks confused*

Comment: @annakata This solution (placing calls just before `</form>` closing tag) is actually genius. It allowed to separate ASP page lifecycle from terrible, browser-dependent events. It's also a reason, why it's so easy now to build i.e. full server-side alert API that uses pure javascript to show/hide or animate etc. particular elements. They've done **fantastic** job with that and thanks to that we can execute **any** JS code we want from server-side events. ♥ x100