# ASP.NET How do I get this jQuery to work persistently across page loads / post backs?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, jquery, html

In ASP.NET I'm trying to use mColorPicker (http://blog.meta100.com/post/600571131/mcolorpicker) with a page I have.

It works on initial page load, can pick the colors fine and I have it hooked up how I want. However, when I update the page (click a button to display another panel / hide other ones), it suddenly stops working as if the javascript isn't there.

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#color3').bind('colorpicked', function () {
      $(".P_FrameDisplay_222").css("background-color", $(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
...
<div style="margin: 5px; float: left;">
  <input type="color" id="color3" value="#ff0667" data-text="hidden" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; border-style: none;" />
</div>
```

I've had this problem before with different javascript code, and to fix it I use this pageload javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
    imagePreview();
  }
</script>
```

How can I get this to work persistently across page loads / post backs?

Comment: **Please**, JavaScript is **not** java.

Comment: Are you using any updatepanels? When the updatepanels refresh they lose any js event bindings and you need to rebind them using the script manager or live events

Comment: Are you mixing jQuery with UpdatePanels on the same page?

Comment: Yeah I'm using update panels (one update panel) and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you use updatepanels, in that case you can use the page request manager which manages partial page updates. Like this:

```
//some initialization code

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {
    //some initialization code
});
```

Comment: pageLoad is the same thing, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602441/whats-the-different-between-asp-net-ajax-pageload-and-javascript-window-onload

Comment: @Josiah, they are similair but not the same. For instance, you can not have multiple pageLoad (for example one pageLoad on the page and one in an external js-file).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using update panels (I am assuming because of the `pageLoad` function). So remember whatever you run on `$(document).ready`, you will also need to run in the `pageLoad` funciton (if the content is replace).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the latest* jQuery, try this snippet, but put it outside the update panel: (assuming #color3 will only show up once, if you need it to work on a class of elements you should define a ... class)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#color3').live('colorpicked', function () {
      $(".P_FrameDisplay_222").css("background-color", $(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

- As of jQuery 1.4 the `.live()` method supports *custom events* as well as all JavaScript events that bubble. [emphasis mine]