# Photoswipe same source code but output not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, photoswipe

I have this piece of code, which refreshes the content of an ul.

It works on the first load, where the content of ul is directly loaded, but i am making new  content every 10 seconds so that user can always get new content.

The source code of content delivered by javascript call is exactly same as the first load. Then also javascript  call does not work

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#vbar").load(location.href+" #vbar>*","");
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

The html code is:

```
<ul  id="vbar" class="gallery">           
    <li>
        <a href="http://i2.listal.com/image/3550836/600full-taylor-swift.jpg" rel="external">Taylor Swift  </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://i2.listal.com/image/303530/600full-jessica-lange.jpg" rel="external">Jessica Lange  </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://i2.listal.com/image/2844304/600full.jpg" rel="external">  </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://i2.listal.com/image/524086/600full-caroline-ribeiro.jpg" rel="external">Caroline Ribeiro  </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://i2.listal.com/image/2402821/600full-francine-dee.jpg" rel="external">Francine Dee  </a>
    </li>                
</ul>
```

I have tried no cache and used this code in header then also no use

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

live code here

```
    http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/newphoto12.php
```

in addition to that can i change the urlwhen new content are inserted

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, setTimeout not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495903/jquery-settimeout-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#vbar").load(location.href+" #vbar>*","");
    }, 10000);
});
</script>
```

BUT, a better way is explained by [@Cletus in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1495905/662581).

There is a carousel in the example that [you linked in the comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607175/same-source-code-but-output-not-working#comment32684058_21610330), the issue right now is that while in the carousel, the `setTimeout` doesn't update the carousel

The solutions:

- Create an array to store ALL the images that are being updated.
- Update the imgs in the carousel, calling the carousel in the setTimeout

In both, you need to see if the code in the carousel is blocking the code of the timeout. Check with chrome dev tools, or even an **alert('test');** should do the job.

Comment: If it was .Net I would say to use [page request management (aka prm)][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433458/asp-net-how-do-i-get-this-jquery-to-work-persistently-across-page-loads-post-b/4433708#4433708]

Comment: where you have used live/on in code given by you. in my case it did not work.it is giving same output as my code in question

Comment: My mistake, I was reading one thing without anything to do with your problem, and followed that instead. I fix it for you.

Comment: see this page it is exactly what you said but it is not working. earlier also i was able to refresh the content but i want it to be used when users are going through images http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/newphoto12.php

Comment: 1. Nice pictures over there. 2. It worked for me (the update outside the images carousel). 3. The carousel code is probably blocking the first one. Try add a function to call both (carousel + setTimeout). and a function with the setTimeout (so you don't need to replicate your code)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47028/discussion-between-user3026718-and-michel)