# ASP.net page load on clientside

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, client-side

What is event for pageload on clientside?

```
 function pageLoad() {
            cbvalcs.SetSelectedIndex(1);
        }
```

I tried this, but nothing happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You may have to include the correct signature.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

To create an ASP.NET page load event, you must first register the handler.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);
```

`applicationLoadHandler` being your javascript function.  This registration can take place in the page load event.

So in your case:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(pageLoad);

function pageLoad() {
        cbvalcs.SetSelectedIndex(1);
    }
```

This can work for partial postbacks as well as full.

For a through dressing of the topic MSDN's [ASP.NET AJAX Client Life-Cycle Events](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx) has all the information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `window.onload`

There are some good articles about [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) and [Using window.onload](http://javascript.about.com/library/blonload.htm)

Comment: This will not work for ajax callbacks. You need to used the client side pageLoad event that is reserved by the asp.net ajax client side library. See: http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx

Comment: @bleeeah: of course, but OP not specifically asking for ajax callback. Since it asking for handling page load on client side I gave java script solution !!

Comment: Yes, but window.onload will not be called (on the client side) after an ajax callback, where as pageLoad will. He has tagged the question as "ajax", so I assume he want's to handle the page load on the client side after an asp.net ajax callback.

Comment: @bleeeah: Yes .. it will perform differently **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602441/whats-the-different-between-asp-net-ajax-pageload-and-javascript-window-onloa**

Comment: Is there after page load event, or something like that, as I need to set value of combobox, but I need serverside page load to be finished first, so cb is filled. Thanks.

Comment: @elninho: if you need the server side page load to finish first, why looking for client side pageload?? What you trying to achieve here?

Comment: If I change selected item on serverside, I can't change it manualy later, it trows error, so when I need to change selected item of combobox, I need to do it on clientside.

Comment: @elninho: It can't be. Anyway, is your main objective is to change the selected item in client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jquery`, then use `$(document).ready`