# Javascript onload not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am creating a website which has two div tags and two radio buttons. The div is to be displayed on the basis of radio button selected. On page load I pass the value of radio button from main page and accordingly I display div. It works well with chrome and firefox but showing problem in IE. I am using IE 11. I have not tried with other versions of IE.
My code is as follows:

```
    <asp:RadioButton ID="mail_stat" Text="Mailwise Statistics" runat="server" GroupName="stat_select" onclick="ch(1)" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="aggegrate_stat" Text="Aggegrate Statistics" runat="server" GroupName="stat_select" onclick="ch(2)" ClientIDMode="Static" />

    <div id="first">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_pro_id" runat="server" Text="Promotion Id"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_pro_id" runat="server" Width="101px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_sub" runat="server" Text="Subject"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_sub" runat="server" Width="301px" Height="16px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    <div id="second">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" required="true" placeholder="Start Date"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" required="true" placeholder="End Date"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My java script is as follows:

```
    <%--Javascript for radiobuttion on load--%>              
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function () {
        if (mail_stat.checked == true)
        {
            ch(1);
        }
        else if (aggegrate_stat.checked == true)
        {
            ch(2);
        }
    }
</script> 

<%--Javascript for radiobuttion--%>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#first').hide();
     $('#second').hide();
     $('stat2').hide();
     function ch(id) {
         if (id == '1') {
             $('#first').show();
             $('#second').hide();
             $('#stat2').hide();
         }
         else if (id == '2') {
             $('#first').hide();
             $('#second').show();
             $('#stat2').show();
         }
     }
 </script>
```

Please help.

Comment: Is the element being fetched? try `$("#mail_stat").is(":checked")`

Comment: Look at: [What's the different between ASP.NET AJAX pageLoad() and JavaScript window.onload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602441/whats-the-different-between-asp-net-ajax-pageload-and-javascript-window-onloa)

Answer (score 1):

`onload` is not defined in the right scope. Try:

```
document.onload = function () {
```

Comment: The same thing is working with firefox and chrome. Thought I tried your suggestion it didn't work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't stored radio button in variable in javascript.
It should be like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mail=document.getElementById('mail_stat');
    var aggegrate=document.getElementById('aggegrate_stat');
onload = function () {
    if (mail.checked == true)
    {
        ch(1);
    }
    else if (aggegrate.checked == true)
    {
        ch(2);
    }
}
```