# Infinite scroll with ASP.NET Web Forms using PageMethods

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've been trying to make something like an infinite scroll work but with no success. And after searching a lot around the web i'm asking the question myself.

About the code,
In the masterPage.Master i've put:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

On another page in the code behind i have a method like this that is going to be called by the script:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static List<agendaList> GetEvents(int startAt, int howMany)
{

    ...

    return eventsListNew.OrderByDescending(p => p.data).Skip(startAt).Take(howMany).ToList<agendaList>();
}
```

In the page i added the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {

            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()-$(window).height()) {
                GetEvents();

            }
        });
    });

    function GetEvents() {
        var howMany = 10;
        var startAt = $(".mason_script").size();
        console.log(startAt);

        PageMethods.GetEvents(startAt, howMany);


    }

    function OnGetPostsComplete(Events) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Events.length; i++) {

            $("#list_eventos_content").last().append("<ul>"+
                            Events[i].title + "</h2><p>" +
                            Events[i].data + "</p></div>" + "</ul>");
        }
    }

</script>
```

It says PageMethods is not defined!
Specifically in the console i get:
Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined

I tryed using the ajax method but with no success either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var howMany = 10;
            var startAt = $(".mason_script").size();
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                //GetEvents();

                console.log(startAt);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //async: true,
                    url: "default.aspx/GetEvents",
                    //url: '<%= ResolveUrl("ConsultaPedidos.aspx/GetClients") %>',
                    //data: {startAt:startAt,howMany:howMany},
                    data: JSON.stringify({ startAt: startAt, howMany: howMany }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () { alert("success"); },
                    error: function () {alert("it was not a success");}
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think the website is already ajax enabled because it's done with visual studio 2010 and i think i have all the necessary bins (i even added System.Web.Extensions.dll to project)

I don't know if this helps to find the problem, but inside the source code after the body element i have the following:

```
<body id="body" class="home">
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="./Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1Mg9kFgJmD2QWAgIDDxYCHgVjbGFzcwUEaG9tZRYCAgEPZBYIAgQPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZAIFD2QWBAIDDxYCHwFoZAIFDxYCHwFoZAIIDxYCHwFoZAIJD2QWAmYPFgIfAWhkZHECEx2bRG9W3HRdtf7e7U4T5JxcYTUIOFqhiAfLIgzr" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=eTLIdTUaKcPvbbHq3uBMJMuE5EuUKGo_QXsf5WdWsog2Gpmfy9qkIK_-y74XUCFlxJFADxQgAgshTA379vvKJGJvi4Ikqiv1yEvS7hpyqVc1&amp;t=635918767619348548" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=qkRHwPohnv0qxNzn-8f9Xk8Z0dBG23n8MDuOOCYf4anPCmyRNRWeCNNgCauDnRlVqW5NKLUOVIfNjW56x6pHNSKmtX7CBH7SpCqDvmzy-NHrCoITbgWSVLGcKILzzGQ1Qlpwpc9IIxnLVQ51v9Kz9DCgKlPHgukhQEeDMmKkQtiLHT1xZPJVocodYa8aG11L0&amp;t=40eb3b32" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('Falha ao carregar estrutura ASP.NET Ajax do lado do cliente.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=gU20UmsqL_uPpdXkHzmyFnlCqFiRG-TM2_Qv0ZALZUtlYUJwYdUdoCXOyXFrEkZWVT92wbL9D1m0HngfHHZW6U8GVV-j6jTKDIjQ4UrIHIXmsJyijp8fEm7m7Qeq-8buVg1yHzCv2Zqt_ktAHum363tvYlDt3B2fmD8Q3YF2jvkK8HbizNFHmiEcaIil3BlR0&amp;t=40eb3b32" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CA0B0334" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAALKL6JprTutrB5uCf6KA5FA2RsWv7CsEAlbyK1tt2kzFFESTmnJ8bzYWS2HmzbItmQmobFjEmOUyk9VeVTmAEW9" />
</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$hidMenu" id="hidMenu" value="menu_home" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', 'form1', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>
```

Only then comes the rest of the page and the script that calls the PageMethod.

Thanks

Comment: Try putting it in the function `pageLoad(s, e) { }` handler instead, jquery might run before ASP.NET AJAX framework is initialized (some backstory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602441/whats-the-different-between-asp-net-ajax-pageload-and-javascript-window-onloa).

Comment: "it" what? you mean the public static function that gets called by the script? but i can't use the directives there it gives error.

Comment: Yes sorry the PageMethods call - if you open up the page and click view source, I think it defines PageMethods as script in the page (if I recall).

Comment: I've posted what appears on source code.

Comment: OK thanks, is that running the app and then doing view source on the browser?  In that snippet, I don't see PageMethods class defined anywhere....  (Maybe it's not supposed to be, been a while since I've done anything with that, but just checking)...

Comment: Yes, it's through the view source in the browser. In the template code instead of those last scripts i have <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>