# How to detect a postback in frontend (aspx)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I need to detect a postback in the frontend so I can use it with JQuery to change a class on page load. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check for IsPostBack in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719/how-can-i-check-for-ispostback-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stolen from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719/how-can-i-check-for-ispostback-in-javascript):

On the server side have this

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
   // NOTE: the following uses an overload of RegisterClientScriptBlock() 
   // that will surround our string with the needed script tags 
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "IsPostBack", "var isPostBack = true;", true);
}
```

On client side this

```
if(isPostBack) {
   // do your thing
}
```

Comment: How do I get the ClientScript object. I typed it in but I am not getting an intellisense to add a namespace.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe try Page.ClientScript?  It's part of System.Web.UI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript.aspx

Answer (score 8):

You can check the IsPostBack property.  Eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var isPostBack = <%=Page.IsPostBack.ToString().ToLower()%>;

        if (isPostBack)
        {
             alert("Postback");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I put this variable inside the header tag of my asp.net web forms page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isPostBack = ("true"==="<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>");
</script>
```

The var contains a Boolean. The comparison can probably be shortened.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

if you're using jquery it has to go after(jquery goes nuts otherwise):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });

   var isPostBack = <%=Convert.ToString(Page.IsPostBack).ToLower()%>;
```

Then

```
    function whatever(){
            if (isPostBack){
            //Whatever you want to do
            }else{
            //Whatever else you want to do
            }
    }
```

I'm actually using it with jquery to show a web service status box then force a postback to refresh a ListView, so when it posts back it doesn't invoke the web service or show the status box just the updated ListView data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[href^='javascript:__doPostBack']").click(function () {
    // do something
});
```