# Is there such a thing as 'if (!Page.IsPostBack)' in jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to detect if when the page loads it is a postback or just the page loading?

Comment: As in as .Net postback ?

Comment: This has been asked a lot, the accepted answer here is a good example of what James suggests:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719/how-can-i-check-for-ispostback-in-javascript

Comment: @Russ I figured it had been asked a lot, but I couldn't find any references to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript has no concept of post back. The simplest way to detect this client-side would be to have **[Insert Your Server Side Language Here]** write/set a JavasScript variable on post back.

In C#, it would look a bit like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), 
         "isPostBack", 
         String.Format("var isPostback = {0};", IsPostBack.ToString().ToLower()),
         true);
```

JavaScript:

```
if(isPostback) {
     // Postback specific logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an asp:hiddenfield which gets its value on page_load.

On the client you can get the value as a string using jQuery, compare it to 'true' resulting in a boolean.

HTML:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnIsPostback" />
```

VB.NET (in page_load):

```
Me.hdnIsPostback.Value = Me.IsPostBack
```

Javascript:

```
var isPostback = $("#<%=hdnIsPostback.ClientID%>").val().toLowerCase() === "true";
```