# How to keep jquery modal open after postback?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am having an empty div and i am  using LOAD method of jquery and getting data from another aspx page. it works fine. it gets File upload and button control from that page. now when i click on the button my button code doesn't get called and my dialog gets close.

jQuery On Page1.aspx

```
var checkP = $('#<%= productName.ClientID %>').val();
checkP = checkP.replace(/\ /g, '-');
$("#midDiv").load("UploadImages.aspx?prodName=" + checkP + " #midDiv");
$("#midDiv").dialog();
//It Shows Dialog With File Upload Option & Button Option.
```

Page1.aspx

```
 <div id="midDiv">

</div>
```

Page2.aspx

```
<div id="midDiv">     
<asp:FileUpload ID="productsImages" CssClass="hid" runat="server" />     
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="uploadImageTemp" Text="Button" />      
</div>
```

Page2.aspx.cs //Code Behind

```
protected void uploadImageTemp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some Work Here...
}
```

Is there any way that my button code gets called or is there any way to keep jQuery modal open ?

Comment: I do something similar with a Bootstrap Modal. What I do is add a data-attribute to the div(from the code behind, uploadButton) and then when the page is refreshed after postback I have jQuery search for the attribute and pop the modal.

Comment: could you please show me how to perform this ? i tried every damn thing but none of them worked :(

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/59730/335905

Answer (score 0):

Append your dialog in form like below.

```
var checkP = $('#<%= productName.ClientID %>').val();
checkP = checkP.replace(/\ /g, '-');
$("#midDiv").load("UploadImages.aspx?prodName=" + checkP + " #midDiv");
$("#midDiv").dialog().parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

Change your button control to link button control.

```
<div id="midDiv">     
<asp:FileUpload ID="productsImages" CssClass="hid" runat="server" />     
  <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="uploadImageTemp" Text="Button" />      
</div>
```

Now call your code behind button click event.