# using AutoPostBack doesn't work when setting input value in JS

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom control which inherits from TextBox.
This allows me to use the TextBox's AutoPostBack property. This property makes the Page_Load method on the parent page fire when I change the value and click out of the text box.
I am setting the value of the rendered text box in JS as follows

```
var outputData = document.getElementById("CameraScannerTextbox1");
outputData.value = barcode.Value;
```

When this code runs I am expecting the Page_Load method to run again.
I have tried things like

```
outputData.focus();
outputData.value = barcode.Value;
outputData.blur();
```

The code in the Page_Load is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Label1.Text = CameraScannerTextbox1.Text;
    }
}
```

So basically I am hoping to have whatever is in barcode.Value set on Label1.Text on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to trigger `onchange` event for `input` since ASP.NET adds postback code to `onchange` attribute. The simplest way is calling `onchange` manually

```
var outputData = document.getElementById("CameraScannerTextbox1");
outputData.value = barcode.Value;
outputData.onchange();
```

For more advanced techniques of simulating `onchange` event see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856602/7775908) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612498/7775908) answers.

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can simply trigger the PostBack yourself with `__doPostBack`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CameraScannerTextbox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <script>
        var outputData = document.getElementById("CameraScannerTextbox1");
        outputData.value = '123456';
        __doPostBack('CameraScannerTextbox1', '');
    </script>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Label1.Text = CameraScannerTextbox1.Text;
        PlaceHolder1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Not that I placed the javascript in a PlaceHolder that is hiddedn on PostBack, otherwise it will create a PostBack loop. But there are other ways to [prevent that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719/how-can-i-check-for-ispostback-in-javascript) also.